# Global Scope fails for included file

Tags: php

Can someone please help me with a scoping issue. I've been looking at this for so long and I just don't see why this isn't working:

connection.php

```
<?php

$hostname = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$username = "xxxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxx";
$db_name = "xxxxxxxx";

function isSecure() {
  return (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off')
      || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443;
}

global $link;
$link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $db_name);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}

?>
```

builder.php

```
<?php
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $connection = $path . '/scripts/connection.php';
    include_once ($connection);

    session_start();
    $club_id = $_SESSION['club_id'];
    
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        trigger_error("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Workout_types
            WHERE club_id=$club_id
            ORDER BY type";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or trigger_error("Error description:" . mysqli_error($link) . "done");
    
?>
```

and I get the dreaded

> mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in...

error.

---

Implementing the troubleshooting tips below, I changed a couple of lines.

builder.php:

```
require_once ("../scripts/connection.php");
```

connection.php:

```
if (!$link) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
```

It still doesn't work, but the errors are a bit different:

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in G:\PleskVhosts\example.com\httpdocs\workouts\builder.php on line 114
PHP Warning:  mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in G:\PleskVhosts\example.com\httpdocs\workouts\builder.php on line 114
PHP Notice:  Error description:done in G:\PleskVhosts\example.com\httpdocs\workouts\builder.php on line 114
```

where line 114 is the `mysqli_query` line.

I checked the GoDaddy docs, and that path is correct.

---

Just to prove that my include path was correct, I added this to `connection.php`:

```
global $test;
$test = "hello world";
```

Then in `builder.php`, I added a line `echo $test;`, and it printed `hello world` with no trouble whatsoever.

---

I should mention two other things could be helpful:

1. The code that I posted for `builder.php` is embedded in html code for a web page. It's the only php code in that file.
2. I originally wrote this code about 5 years ago, and it's been functioning flawlessly until I upgraded the php version on my server from 5.6.40 to 7.3.27. That's when it began to fail.

Comment: Could you replace `include_once` with `require_once`, and see if you get a different kind of error? And replace `if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {` with `if (!$link) {` in connection.php

Comment: are you sure  connection file path is right

Comment: Good ideas. I tried them and edited my post with the results. Thank you!

Comment: Seeing your latest edition that's disturbing and unexplainable.. Another test you can do is to move all the logic of connection.php into builder.php and see the results you have

Comment: Wrap the connection in a function that returns the handle.Then in builder call something like $link=connection();

Comment: @ThomasG I did that during all of my trouble shooting efforts. It works perfectly if I do that. But that is exactly the reason for using the `include` statement. I use this `connection.php` statement countless times for other database calls, so I obviously don't want to repeat that code over and over again.

Comment: Why `global` in the first place? With the example given, you are not even switching into any function scope.

Comment: replice global to $GLOBALS

Comment: do some more debug. paste connection code in query page. check work or not.
check whether have you closed connection before use.
check query is correct like quotations

Comment: @CBroe I agree. I don't think it is necessary. I added it because I saw so many posts where the issue was resolved by adding that to the variable declaration.